# How to get 2 urls from 2 Options in one form

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form action="Url1" method="post">
<select class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is a example code for my problem. What i want is to get different urls When select *Text 1 Option* or *Text 2 Option*. How can i do it?

Edit: I want to get different web URLs for these 2 options. For an example when someone select Text 1 Option, He must be directed to URL 1 And when someone selects Text 2 option He must be directed to URL 2

Comment: With javascript.

Comment: ikr, I'm asking if someone show me an example code :)

Comment: Unclear if you’re asking how to do ajax or how to do a basic html select.  Why not just put the urls in the option’s value attribute?

Comment: OK, the confusion is from the phrase “get different web urls”.  That leads me to think that you need to acquire the urls from somewhere. If it’s your own database, just fill it in when you generate the page.  Step 1 is to make your example show that you know how to do this, and give us relevant code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id attribute to your selector and get the selected value using java and use window.location to redirect on selected url

The corrected code is as below.

Try this ..

```
<form action="Url1" method="post">
<select name="url" id ="url" class="selectpicker"
<option value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Deposit 
Now</button>
</form>     

<script type = "text/javascript">

        function Redirect() {

          var e = document.getElementById("url");
           var strUrl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
           window.location = strUrl;
        }

  </script>
```

Comment: I want to get different web URLs for these 2 options. For an example when someone select Text 1 Option, He must be directed to URL 1 And when someone selects Text 2 option He must be directed to URL 2

Comment: Hi as the following javascript to redirect <script type = "text/javascript">
       
            function Redirect() {
  
              var e = document.getElementById("url");
               var strUrl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
               window.location = strUrl;
            }
         
      </script> select URL